# @Math masti 1234567

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: !Solve This]

—+—=8
×
— ×—=9
= =
—   5

```
  Solve this plz
```

Comment: Fairly sure this is been asked before

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil You can *read* this??!

Comment: @Stiv no but I recognise the image :P

Answer (score 1):

Answer:   ..............................

> [image]